# Excel Formula - Count Column M Date If Column E Date Has Passed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to count the amount of dates in Col M that have passed Col E

For example

```
Col E 
Due Date 19/03/17

Col M
Completed Date 23/03/17
```

I tried

```
=COUNTIF(M:M,M:M>E:E)
```

but this didn't work. It doesn't seem to like adding the column values. I managed to do cell to cell but when it comes to columns it really doesn't want to work. Its probably simple but giving me serious headache ATM.

ADDITIONAL:

The formula im trying to change is:

```
=COUNTIFS($M:$M,"<="&G6,$M:$M,">"&F6)
```

G6=The date of 24/03/17

F6=The date of 17/03/17

Im trying to get it to count the days between these two ranges that are completed outside of the requested date if that makes sense.

Comment: your M isn't a date.

Comment: In case your date in column M is a **Typo**, then use the Formula `=COUNTIF(M:M,">"&E6)` (not in Column M), where E6 holds the date criteria (in your example `19/03/17`)

Comment: Countif criteria doesn't work like this. Add another column with `=M1>E1`, pull down, and countif the `TRUE` values. Or you can piss blood and do it with an array formula.

Comment: Sorry was a Typo :) 

I have tried that as well @ShaiRado but unfortunately doesnt work either.

Comment: @vacip I want to avoid adding an additional column

Comment: where did you enter this formual ? what cell ? are all of your cells formatted as dates ?

Comment: @ShawnCartwright Do column M cells include the entire string `Completed Date 23/03/17`, or just the date?

Comment: E has a header Due Date then dates underneath and M Completed Date then dates underneath. 

So the cells below the headers are DATE ONLY. 

Cells are formatted as short date. 

The formula can be anywhere but atm is in Y1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column headers are as you say, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(M:M>E:E))
```

For speed, you may want to decrease the number of rows counted.

If your column headers might be different, I would suggest using either a dynamic named range, or a "Table" so as to exclude the header and include only the used rows.  Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CompletedDateTable>DueDateTable))
```

Note that in the first formula, I used the `N` function, and in the second, I used the double unary operator.  Just two different ways of accomplishing the same thing of converting `TRUE FALSE`  to `1 0`.

Comment: Thats great Ron. Im struggling to incorporate that into my formula which I have added above as additional. I dont know if you can help there. You have taught me something here so thank you for that.

Comment: Ive worked it out. Thank you Ron.                                   

     **=SUMPRODUCT(--(E:E<=--G6),--(M:M>=--F6))**

Just incase anyone else wanted this :)

Comment: Actually that isnt working correctly either. Not sure what im doing wrong. Thought it was on the right path

Comment: @ShawnCartwright This is a different question from your first.  I would suggest you post a new question, and, in order to present your problem clearly, please first read the HELP pages for information as to  [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Ron. Thought that might be the case. Thank you for your help.